# Modifying JQuery function to run on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been struggling to modify this function such that it runs on the click of a button with a class of 'boldbutton'. Whenever I modify it, the functionality changes. I really seems as though this function needs to start with jQuery('textarea').

How would I modify this function so that it

a) retains it functionality and,

b) runs only on the click of $('.boldbutton')

```
<script>

jQuery('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var text = jQuery(this).val();

    var start = this.selectionStart;

    var end = this.selectionEnd;

    var selection = '<b>' + text.substring(start, end) + '</b>';

    text = text.substring(0, start) + selection + text.substring(end);

    jQuery(this).val(text);

    this.selectionStart = start;

    this.selectionEnd = start + selection.length;

});

</script>
```

Thanks so much for your help!!

Comment: What's the problem with using `$(".boldbutton").click(function() { code });`

Comment: Is there single `textarea` in your code or multiple? If multiple then you want to call this function for all `textarea` when button click?

Comment: single textarea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a click event listener to your button using the `.click()` method.

Instead of targetting `this` in your code (as `this` now refers to the button clicked, not the textarea), you can target the textarea element using `$("textarea")`. To access vanilla properties, you can use `$("textarea")[0]` which will allow you to use `.selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`.

See working example below:

```js
$('.boldbutton').click(function() {
  var $textarea = $("textarea");
  var text = $textarea.val();
  var start = $textarea[0].selectionStart;
  var end = $textarea[0].selectionEnd;
  
  var selection = '<b>' + text.substring(start, end) + '</b>';
  text = text.substring(0, start) + selection + text.substring(end);
  
  $textarea.val(text);
  $textarea.selectionStart = start;
  $textarea.selectionEnd = start + selection.length;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
<br />
<button class="boldbutton">Bold</button>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Comment: Do you know why the selection doesn't remain selected after the user clicks the button? Not a big deal. I'm just curious.

Comment: @JasonHoward no worries! I think it's because you "unfocus" (click off of the textbox) the textbox, which means the selection will disappear. So it happens not just when you click the button, but rather when you click anywhere else but the textbox

Comment: Ah, ok! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Update your code as below. Update `jQuery('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {` to `jQuery('.boldbutton').on('click', function(e) {`. Change `jQuery(this)` to `jQuery('textarea')`. Add `var textArea = jQuery('textarea')[0];`
 And use `textArea` instead of `this`.

```
<script>

    jQuery('.boldbutton').on('click', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var text = jQuery('textarea').val();
        var textArea = jQuery('textarea')[0];

        var start = textArea.selectionStart;

        var end = textArea.selectionEnd;

        var selection = '<b>' + text.substring(start, end) + '</b>';

        text = text.substring(0, start) + selection + text.substring(end);

        jQuery(textArea).val(text);

        textArea.selectionStart = start;

        textArea.selectionEnd = start + selection.length;

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try wrap the whole JS code inside

````
$(document).ready(()=> {

})```
````